# Is move_uploaded_file necessary for local storage prior to cloud storage?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am working on an application that allows users to upload a picture to the system and we store this picture on cloud storage (S3). Currently, once the picture is uploaded we're processing their file by copying the temp file locally via `move_uploaded_file()` and then using that local file to upload it to S3. Is this local copy a necessity or is it possible to override this step and directly upload to cloud storage without ever storing a local copy?

```
$temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$target = ABSPATH.'uploads/';
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$targetFile = $target . $name;
move_uploaded_file($temp,$targetFile);

//upload local file to s3
$this->saveToCloud($this->s3Path,$targetFile);
```

Before the file gets copy to local storage via `move_uploaded_file` it lives in tmp php storage:

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpx3uBiT
```

What I'd like to do is simply:

```
 $this->saveToCloud($this->s3Path,$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So long as the cloud storage is accessible by the webserver user and the path and protocol are compatible with `move_uploaded_file()` then just move it to the cloud.

Comment: We're using the AWS S3 SDK for the file upload to the cloud via , `MultipartUploader()`, the wrapper function takes in a path and file name. This is where the local copy comes in handy and this is what I am having difficulty with.

Comment: `$this->saveToCloud($this->s3Path,$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);` without `move_uploaded_file` will work fine (as long as it's done within the same request as the file upload since the tmp file is removed when the PHP request terminates).

Comment: @drew010, if you look at the temporary path example above, its a hash without a file type, when I try to access it directly, its not found.

Comment: The temp file will only be there during the life of the PHP request.  That's probably why you can't access it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are thinking about performance issues then you should NOT care about `move_uploaded_file` because it just do some checks and just rename it's name(path). CPU consume is minimal. Unless the destination of the temporary file is in an external hard disk and it will need network transportation.

If you want to make server process lighter then you can consider using *AWS SDK Javascript for browser* and do the file upload directly from client browser to your S3 bucket (check this link for how to do it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html#s3-example-photo-album-adding-photos). Using this way you should take in consideration making a HTTP Request just to save file information on your database after/before file uploads.

If you are not interested using *AWS SDK Javascript for browser* then you can try: 

`$this->saveToCloud($this->s3Path,$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);`

but I'm not sure if it works, I didn't try it.

I hope this helps